# What is the command line equivalent of "Clean / Purge Data" in docker?

Tags: docker

When I want to remove everything (running or not), I can just go to `Troubleshoot` and hit the <kbd>Clean / Purge data</kbd> button. This would remove all docker data, without resetting settings to factory defaults. Is there a single line command to achieve same thing?

**P.S.:** I know about `docker system prune`, but it is not exactly the same. I want to reset everything, not just the unused.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the combination of docker rm to delete running containers and docker system prune to delete everything:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q);docker system prune --volumes -a -f
```

Comment: I guess there is no such built-in command like `docker reset`.